# Upload de 12 campos de documentos em PHP

Tags: php, upload

Estou fazendo 12 uploads em uma mesma página e estou usando um código *burro*, pois estou me repetindo. Mas não sei fazer o loop.

Mas esse não está sendo o problema. O caso é que só está funcionando para os quatro primeiros campos, estando vazios ou não.

Eis o código:

```
    if (isset($_POST['idCliente'])) {
    $idCliente = $_POST['idCliente'];
//    echo $idCliente;    
    $uploaddir = 'assets/clientes/docs/';
    $contratoSocial = $_FILES['ContratoSocial'];
    $cnpj = $_FILES['cnpj'];
    $InscricaoEstadual = $_FILES['InscricaoEstadual'];
    $InscricaoMunicipal = $_FILES['InscricaoMunicipal'];
    $ComprovanteEndereco = $_FILES['ComprovanteEndereco'];
    $agefip = $_FILES['agefip'];
    $rg = $_FILES['rg'];
    $cpf = $_FILES['cpf'];
    $comprovantereisdencia = $_FILES['comprovantereisdencia'];
    $certidaonascimento = $_FILES['certidaonascimento'];
    $certidaocasamento = $_FILES['certidaocasamento'];

    /* DOCUMENTOS OBRIGATÓRIOS PARA EMPRESA 
    1 Contrato Social
    2 Cartão CNPJ
    3 Inscrição Estadual
    4 Inscrição Municipal
    5 Comprovante de Endereço da Empresa
    6 AGEFIP
    */
    /* DOCUMENTOS OBRIGATÓRIOS PARA VIDA 
    8 R.G.
    9 C.P.F.
    10 Comprovante de Residência
    11 Certidão de Nascimento
    12 Certidão de Casamento
    */


    if($contratoSocial != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['ContratoSocial']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ContratoSocial']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '1';
        $sql_contratoSocial = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
            mysql_query($sql_contratoSocial) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($cnpj !=''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['cnpj']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cnpj']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '2';
        $sql_cnpj = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
            mysql_query($sql_cnpj) or die(mysql_error());
    }


   if($InscricaoEstadual !=''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['InscricaoEstadual']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['InscricaoEstadual']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '3';
        $sql_InscricaoEstadual = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_InscricaoEstadual) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($InscricaoMunicipal != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['InscricaoMunicipal']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['InscricaoMunicipal']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '4';
        $sql_InscricaoMunicipal = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_InscricaoMunicipal) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($ComprovanteEndereco != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['ComprovanteEndereco']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ComprovanteEndereco']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '5';
        $sql_ComprovanteEndereco = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_ComprovanteEndereco) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    if($agefip != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['agefip']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['agefip']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '6';
        $sql_agefip = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_agefip) or die(mysql_error());
    }   


    if($rg != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['rg']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rg']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '8';
        $sql_rg = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_rg) or die(mysql_error());
    }        

    if($cpf != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['cpf']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cpf']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '9';
        $sql_cpf = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_cpf) or die(mysql_error());
    }  

    if($comprovantereisdencia != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['comprovantereisdencia']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['comprovantereisdencia']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '10';
        $sql_comprovantereisdencia = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_comprovantereisdencia) or die(mysql_error());
    }  

    if($certidaonascimento !=''){    
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['certidaonascimento']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['certidaonascimento']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '11';
        $sql_certidaonascimento = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_certidaonascimento) or die(mysql_error());
    }          

    if($certidaocasamento != ''){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['certidaocasamento']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['certidaocasamento']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    echo $nomArquivo = $uploadfile;
    $idTipoDocumento = '12';
        $sql_certidaocasamento = 'INSERT INTO documentos (idCliente, idTipoDocumento, nomArquivo) VALUES ('.$idCliente.','.$idTipoDocumento.',"'.$nomArquivo.'")';
        mysql_query($sql_certidaocasamento) or die(mysql_error());
    }        


    header('location:lista-propostas.php?docs=1');
}
```

Aqui o código HTML:

```
      <form id="form1" name="form1" action="upload-docs.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" id="idCliente" name="idCliente" value="'.$qt['idCliente'].'">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<h3 class="login-form-text2">Documentos</h3>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Contrato Social
                                    <input type="file" id="ContratoSocial" name="ContratoSocial" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Cartão CNPJ
                                    <input type="file" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Inscrição Estadual
                                    <input type="file" id="InscricaoEstadual" name="InscricaoEstadual" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Inscrição Municipal
                                    <input type="file" id="InscricaoMunicipal" name="InscricaoMunicipal" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Comprovante de Endereço
                                    <input type="file" id="ComprovanteEndereco" name="ComprovanteEndereco" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Cartão AGEFIP
                                    <input type="file" id="agefip" name="agefip" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                R.G.
                                    <input type="file" id="rg" name="rg" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                C.P.F.
                                    <input type="file" id="cpf" name="cpf" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Comprovante de Residência
                                    <input type="file" id="comprovantereisdencia" name="comprovantereisdencia" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Certidão de Nascimento
                                    <input type="file" id="certidaonascimento" name="certidaonascimento" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col l3 s12">
                                Certidão de Casamento
                                    <input type="file" id="certidaocasamento" name="certidaocasamento" class="dropify" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg gif bmp pdf" data-show-errors="true" data-max-file-size="5M" data-default-file="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col l3 s12">
                                    <input type="date" value="" class="datepicker">
                                    <label class="active" for="dataDigitalizacao">Data de Digitalização</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col l3 s12">
                                    <input type="date" class="datepicker" disabled value="' . date('d/m/Y') . '">
                                    </ul>
                                    <label class="active" for="dataAlteracao">Data de Alteração</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <div class="divider"></div>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="atualizar" id="atualizar" onClick="javascript:desabilita();">atualizar
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
```

Já revisei todas as linhas e ainda não descobri o problema, como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Oi Virgilio, eu já havia visto essa página e exemplos. Está me parecendo um problema de max_file_uploads, mas não sei como fixar isso. Será que posso escrever um php.ini e colocar no servidor?

Comment: Não sei exatamente!, mas, você não me mostrou erros e também preciso ver o seu html!

Comment: Eis o código html... é longo!

Comment: `max_file_uploads` verifique no servidor qual é máximo que você pode enviar, ou crie um arquivo com a função `<?php phpinfo();` e verifique o tamanho que você pode enviar.

Comment: Eu criei um php.ini e subi e deu diferença. O servidor lê esse arquivo. Vou fazer agora esse que você sugeriu pra ver o que rola.

Comment: Sim, o servidor lê o php.ini que eu coloquei no server. Hora puz 12, hora puz 20 e o phpinfo(); me informou certinho as mudanças que fiz. Deve ser outro problema. Não estão indo os valores $_POST a partir da 5ª query....

Comment: Seria mais simples então fazer um file para cada um ou seja 12 file identificando cada nome e no código ficaria simples! eu vi um problema que parece multi upload cada campo isso ai dependendo do caso pode mais atrapalhar do que ajudar!